# Sort custom post type items by taxonomy description

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want the portfolio items to be arranged in custom order (based on the category descriptions which I use number values to order)

Current order

```
<ul id="portfolio-cats" class="filter clearfix">
        <li class="sort"><?php _e('Sort Items','themename'); ?>:</li>
        <li><a href="#all" rel="all" class="active"><span><?php _e('All', 'themename'); ?></span></a></li>
        <?php
        foreach ($cats as $cat ) : ?>
        <li><a href="#<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>" rel="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

If I have 3 taxonomies named *Gender*, *Age*, *Height*.

I want the filter beside "All" to display them in above order, based on the taxonomy description.

```
Gender Desc "1", Age Desc "2" etc.
```

I want to to this on mass scale so not just 3 taxonomies, hence the need to number them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) instead of trying to use the description field. It's very lightweight and uses drag-and-drop ordering on the admin end. Then you just `orderby => term_order` when grabbing your terms.